# How to make a js widget/popup/content locker?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm wondering how can i convert a popup so that people will be able to place it on their pages by a Javascript code, Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php?user=USER-ID&pop=POP-UP-ID"></script>
```

I can store all the popup source code and the UserID and PopupID in the Database but i have no idea on how to accomplish the Javascript part.

Basically it is gonna help clients who are not familiar with coding at all to add the popups without any hassle and the 2nd functionality is Analytics system - I want to be able to give them some stats (Impressions, Clicks, CTR etc...) and this js method sound good to me.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can open a popup with `window.open ("http://yourpopupurl","mywindow");`

Since you set `http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php?user=USER-ID&pop=POP-UP-ID` as the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag, I assume this URL loads some dynamically generated JavaScript. Put the above code in this javascript to open the popup.

If `http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php?user=USER-ID&pop=POP-UP-ID` is in fact the generated html code of your popup, you should be using `window.open ("http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php?user=USER-ID&pop=POP-UP-ID","mywindow");` to open the popup instead.

Comment: i was meaning a modal popup not a regular HTML popup. (don't pay attention to the pop-up word, act to the question as i ask about content lockers/widgets/modals.)